# program blanks at net.conn read attempt in client. Does not show and error it just goes blank and stops working

Tags: go, networking

Here is my client

```
    func ClientStart() {
        var dissconnect bool //used for detecting dissconnect
        var previousData []byte
        var packets [][]byte
    
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "0.0.0.0:9999")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        defer conn.Close()
    
        //Create the hello message
        //--------
        
        //-----
        //----->>>>> tracker
        tracker = Newtrack(15 * time.Second) //set timer for 15 seconds
        //----->>>>> tracker end
        //The loop
        for {
            buffer := make([]byte, 1<<16) //create 1 mb buffer //make sure to zero out when finished
    
            _,err := conn.Read(buffer) //read into the buffer
            //This is for more gracefully hnadling the stuff
            if err != nil {
                if err !=  io.EOF {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
                break
            }
    
            packets,previousData, err = Messages.ExtractPackets(append(previousData,buffer...))//extract the packets
    
            //This is where everything gets processed
            for _, value := range packets {
                irc, err := Messages.CreateIrc(value)//get irc
                if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
    
                parse, opcode, err := Messages.Parse(*irc)
                if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
    
                err = handleMessages(*parse,opcode)
                if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
            }
    
            //-+-+-+++++++++++++++++++++++ dissconnect if timer expires
            go func(dis *bool)  {
                for {
                    <-tracker.timer.C
                    fmt.Println("Keepalive not sent from function")
                    break
                }
                *dis = true
            }(&dissconnect)
            if dissconnect {
                fmt.Println("client has not sent keepalive dissconnecting")
                os.Exit(3)
            }
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ timer
    
            sendKeepAlive(conn)
        }
    }
```

and here is my server

```
    func ServerStart() {
        listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:9999")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        defer listener.Close()
    
        for {
            con, err := listener.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                continue
            }
    
            // If you want, you can increment a counter here and inject to handleClientRequest below as client identifier
            go handleClientRequest(con)
        }
    }
    
    func handleClientRequest(conn net.Conn) {
        defer conn.Close()
        var dissconnect bool //used to dissconnect if keep alive fails
        var previousData []byte //holds previous data from for loop
        var packets [][]byte //holds packets in a list
        var label string
        tracker = Newtrack(15 * time.Second) //create a new tracker and set the timer for 15 seconds    
    
        for {
            buffer := make([]byte, 1<<16) // small buffer    
    
            _,err := conn.Read(buffer) //read into the buffer
            //This is for more gracefully hnadling the stuff
            if err != nil {
                if err !=  io.EOF {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
                break
            }
            //extract the packets and any extra
            packets,previousData, err = Messages.ExtractPackets(append(previousData,buffer...))//extract the packets
    
            //print the error
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
    
            //turn the packets into IRC packets
            IRCpackets := make([]Messages.IrcPacket, len(packets)) //create a list of IRC packets len of raw packets
            for index,value := range packets {
                IRC, err := Messages.CreateIrc(value)
    
                if IRC != nil { //if IRC = nil then err likely does not = nil
                    IRCpackets[index] = *IRC //create IRCpackets's for every raw packet
                }
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
            }

            //This is where everything gets processed
            for _, value := range packets {
                irc, err := Messages.CreateIrc(value)//get irc
                if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
    
                parse, opcode, err := Messages.Parse(*irc)
                if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
    
                err = handleMessages(*parse,opcode)
                if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
            }
        }
    }
```

As stated in the title it just sits there and does not carry on. Can you use the same connection to read and write? my read on the server side works just fine and has no issues however I have not attempted to write on the server side yet so I'm unsure if that's the issue

Edit: By stops working I mean it does not do anything past that point in the debugger it just sits there and refuses to move on and I've never seen something like that before.

the client and server are run separately and aren't part of the same process activated by a command line argument. So I can't use the debugger with both.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

> Can you use the same connection to read and write?

Yes. A TCP connection supports two asynchronous streams of data.

It's too much code to read for me (try to reduce it to a minimal compilable example that demonstrates the issue), but I suppose that the problem is the following. If you don't `conn.Write()` on one side, the other side will wait on `conn.Read()` and vice versa.

Comment: I deleted some code

Comment: Thanks! My explanation stays the same. The client and server both read from the connection, but none of them write. Read and Write are blocking operations.

I'm still struggling to understand all of the parts of the code, but the "disconnect" part raises some questions. Why do you start a goroutine on each read in the loop? You use the "disconnect" variable to inform the main goroutine that it should exit. That's not thread-safe as two goroutines access the variable without synchronization.

Comment: I just realized that goroutine will be called in each for loop. Whoops. The point of it is to time for keepalive messages and shut down if it is not received in 15 seconds. It was to prevent the channel from blocking using a timer. I'll change that and come back to it.